# Relationship between torque and force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

While studying Newtonian mechanics, we are concerned with only three laws of motion that describes force and it's relations. But when we switch to rotational dynamics, we are presented with torque and moment of inertia as being the rotational analogue of force and mass.
With no laws other than Newton's laws describing motion of this type. How, did we actually arrived at the idea of torque and moment of inertia from force and other related concepts?

Comment: Related: [Rigid body dynamics derivation from Newton's laws for higher dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471106/206691). (In that question, "higher dimensions" means "more than one dimension.") The answers at least partly explain how the concepts of torque and moment of inertia arise from more-familiar concepts.

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rigid body dynamics derivation from Newton's laws for higher dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471106/)

Comment: If you are interested in the historical context, [hsm.se] might be a more suitable location to ask.